# a congruence equation in number theory

Tags: number-theory

i need to solve a congruence equation x^2-2*y^2=0(mod5) to show every element except zero in a quotient ring Z[x]/(x^2-2,5) has a multiplicative inverse in an abstract algebra problem.

wolfram says the only solution is x=0,y=0 which i was expecting. but i learned number theory an year ago......so i don't remember how to solve this quadratic equation.how can i solve this equation with hands? thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several ways: $1)$ just check $x\equiv 0,1,2,3,4,\, y\equiv 0,1,2,3,4\pmod{5}$ to find all pairs $(x,y)$. There are $25$ different combinations to check.

You can use a trick to make it quicker: $a^2\equiv (-a)^2$, therefore check only $x\equiv 0,1,2,\, y\equiv 0,1,2\pmod{5}$.

$2)$ If $y\equiv 0\pmod{5}$, then $(x,y)\equiv (0,0)\pmod{5}$. Now assume $y\not\equiv 0\pmod{5}$. Then $(xy^{-1})^2\equiv 2\pmod{5}$. By [Quadratic Reciprocity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_reciprocity#.C2.B12_and_the_second_supplement) this is impossible, because $5$ is not of the form $8k\pm 1$.

Comment: this is great.  haven't heard the quadratic reciprocity for a long time though. thank you so much